# How to write bash function to not require quotation marks?

Tags: string, bash, function, escaping

Here is a very simple bash function that takes a message and appends it to the end of file.txt.

```
function n() { 
   message=$1 &&
   echo -e "$message" >> file.txt;
}
```

To add text to this file, I'd simple run `n "text I want to add"`

This is all fine and good, but is there a way to not require the quotation marks? Instead, everything after the function would be considered the message.

`n Everything I write here, after the n, would be saved to the file.txt`

Essentially, I'd be telling bash to stop reading anything after `n` as potentially a function, and to read it only as a character string. I could foresee this being achieved with a different function than `echo`, or by somehow including the quotation marks in the definition of `n`, so that they are invisible when `n` is called.

Comment: Use `"$@"` in the function to get all the arguments.

Comment: depends on what you mean with "everything" be aware of shell expansions \*

Answer (score 2):

Use `$@` to get all the arguments.

```
function n() { 
   echo -e "$@" >> file.txt;
}
```

Note that the shell performs word splitting, wildcard processing, brace expansion, and other expansions on the command line *before* invoking the command/function. There's no way to tell it that the arguments should be left alone other than putting them in quotes. So if you put multiple spaces between a word in your arguments, they'll be collapsed into a single space unless you quote them. And wildcards will be expanded if they match any filenames.